# Most efficient method to store MYSQL options and values in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hitting a dead with the best practice for storing a large amount of options and values in my MYSQL database and then assigning them to properties.  The way I usually do this (example is for real estate) is to create a table called "pool" then have an auto increment value as the ID and a varchar to store the value, in this case "Above Ground" and another row for "In-ground".  Then in my property table I would have a column for "has_pool" with the proper ID value from the "pool" table assigned.  Obviously the problem is that with hundreds of options (fireplace, water view, etc) for each property, my number of database tables will get very large, very fast and my left joins would become out of control on the front side.

Can someone point me in the right direction on what the best practice would be to easily populate new values for the property attributes and keep the query count down to a minimum?  I feel like there is a simple solution but my research so far has not made it apparent to me.  Thank you!

Comment: Probably a bitfield, or store the info as a json array if you want it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is create an 'options' table with four columns: id, menuId, value

Create another table called menus, with two fields; id and name.

Add the menu names (pool, fireplace etc.) to the menus table, and then add the possible values to the options table, including the id of the menu it is related to.

Comment: Thanks, this confirmed what I was thinking.  As far as assigning the correct value to each specific property I assume the best way would be to have a 'property_options" table that would have: id (auto increment), property_id, menuID, option_id?  Thanks again!

Comment: hmm.. not sure if you need a property_options table, just put all the options in the 'options' table, and make sure the menuId references the right category. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'd store all the values serialized (e.g. JSON or XML or YAML) into a blob, and then define inverted index tables for attributes I want to be searchable.

I describe this technique and alternatives in my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).

Also see http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql

Comment: Thanks Bill.  This answer was a bit beyond the scope of what I was looking for (or perhaps my abilities at the moment) but I do appreciate the reply and have bookmarked the links to get deeper into at a later time.